# How do you let a call through in varnish when a cookie "lang" is not set?

Tags: varnish

How do you let a call through in varnish when a cookie "lang" is not set? I want to let a call go through and not return the cache when the cookie "lang" is set and send the request to apache, how do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Bypassing the cache when a lang cookie was not set

In its most basic form, this is the VCL code you need to *pass* requests to the backend that don't contain a `lang` cookie:

```
sub vcl_recv {
    if(req.http.Cookie !~ "(^|([^;]*;)+)\s*lang=([^;]*)\s*($|(;[^;]*)+)") {
        return(pass);
    }
}
```

However, you'll probably need to define some logic in case the `lang` cookie was set.

### Using the value of the lang cookie

The following VCL snippet extracts the language that was set by the `lang` cookie and stores it in `req.http.lang`.

This value is used to create a cache variation per language:

```
sub vcl_recv {
    if(req.http.Cookie !~ "(^|([^;]*;)+)\s*lang=([^;]*)\s*($|(;[^;]*)+)") {
        return(pass);
    } 
    set req.http.lang = regsub(req.http.Cookie,"(^|([^;]*;)+)\s*lang=([^;]*)\s*($|(;[^;]*)+)","\3");
    //Some other logic
    return(hash);
}

sub vcl_hash {
    if(req.http.lang) {
        hash_data(req.http.lang);
    }
}
```

The snippet above also explicitly calls `return(hash)`. At some point you will need to force Varnish to cache when the `lang` cookie is set, because the standard Varnish behavior cache anything when cookies are present.

I added a `//Some other logic` comment, because I'm assuming there will be more logic to bypass the cache. For example when request methods other than `GET` and `HEAD` are used, or for custom URL patterns that need to bypass the cache.

### Avoiding too many cache variations

The `hash_data(req.http.lang)` statement will ensure that a cache variation is created for every value that the `lang` cookie may have.

The danger with that is that users with bad intentions start adding random values to the `lang` cookie to fill the cache.

Keeping this risk in mind, it would make sense to explicitly list the supported languages in your regular expression.

Here's the initial regex:

```
(^|([^;]*;)+)\s*lang=([^;]*)\s*($|(;[^;]*)+)
```

Here's an example with hardcoded supported languages:

```
(^|([^;]*;)+)\s*lang=(en|es|de|it|es|fr|nl)\s*($|(;[^;]*)+)
```

Just tailor this regex to your needs and the languages your web platform supports.